# scope :new_users, :conditions => {['look IS NULL OR look = ?',false]} Getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My scope is

```
scope :new_users, :conditions => {['look IS NULL OR look = ?',false]}
```

But i getting error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
```

Where i am wrong? please correct it. I am using rails3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your scope like:

```
scope :new_users, :conditions => {('look IS NULL OR look = ?',false)}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
scope :new_users, where('look IS NULL OR look = ?', false)
```